# How to change ScrollPhysics dynamically on page changed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to apply NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() every time page is changed either forward/backward and then come back to AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() after 3 seconds.
How would I achieve that behaviour ?

I have tried to setState in onPageChanged listener, but it breaks the page view.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  ScrollPhysics myScrollPhysics = AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics();

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return PageView(
       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       controller: myPageController,
       physics: myScrollPhysics,
       onPageChanged: (index){
         setState((){
           myScrollPhysics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
         })
       },
       children: [...]
     )  
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sould works:
In this function, you wait 3 seconds before changing the state and your physics.

```
void _scrollOn() async {
   myScrollPhysics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
   await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
   setState((){
      myScrollPhysics = AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics();
   })
}
```

```
onPageChanged: (index){
   setState((){
      _scrollOn();
   })
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a ternary operator when you are creating a widget like this:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isScrollable = false;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return PageView(
       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       controller: myPageController,
       physics: isScrollable ? AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() 
                         : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
       onPageChanged: (index){
         setState((){
            isScrollable = !isScrollable;
         })
       },
       children: [...]
     )  
   }
```

Just be sure that you changing the `isScrollable` boolean in the `setState`.

Comment: this approach will  rebuild the PageView on each scroll ryt?

Comment: If you mean , change page by swiping it ,then yes it will